# Dynamically add option elements to <select> in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

**Please understand this question is pertaining to jscript in electron.** 
I have a two .js files that are to be opened and read into individual arrays. I have it set up as two functions inside a main type function.
Each is to be called in the html file inside JavaScript . They are to populate or add selection options to a select input box.

I having a hard time calling them (arrays) so it can be read into the select option code. below is the ('./app.js')

```
var zipArry = []; 
var zipResult = [];
var aniArry = [];
var aniResult = [];

var blah = (function() {

   function zipList(callback) {


    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('.Text1.txt')
    });

    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
        zipArry.push(line);
    });

    lineReader.on('close', function (line) {

    var Ncount = 0;
    for(var x =0; x < zipArry.length; x++){

        zipResult.push(zipArry[x]);

    }
  });
    callback(zipResult);
}



 function aniList(callback) {


    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('./text2.txt')
    });

    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
       aniArry.push(line);
    });

    lineReader.on('close', function (line) {

    var Ncount = 0;
    for(var x =0; x < aniArry.length; x++){

         aniResult.push(aniArry[x]);
        }

  });
   callback(aniResult);
 }
   return {
      ziplist: zipList,
      anilist: aniList
   };
}); 

   module.exports = blah;
```

This is part of the .html file with the JavaScript code. If there is a way to make this easier please explain. I am a noob.

```
var blah = require('./apps2.js');
var Blah= new blah();          
Blah.ziplist();

var select = document.getElementById("zip");  
for (var i= 0; i<zipResult.length; i++){

  var el = document.createElement('option');
      var opt = zipResult[i];
      el.textContent = opt;
      el.value = opt;
      select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. I changed things up and made objects then later exporting them in the html file.

```
var zipArry = []; 
var zipResult = [];
var aniArry = [];
var aniResult = [];

var blah = {

   ziplist: function zipList(callback) {


       var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
          input: require('fs').createReadStream('.Text1.txt')
       });

       lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
           zipArry.push(line);
       });

       lineReader.on('close', function (line) {

          var Ncount = 0;
          for(var x = 0; x < zipArry.length; x++){

             zipResult.push(zipArry[x]);

          }
          callback(zipResult);
       });

   }



   anilist: function aniList(callback) {


       var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
          input: require('fs').createReadStream('./text2.txt')
       });

       lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
           aniArry.push(line);
       });

       lineReader.on('close', function (line) {

           var Ncount = 0;
           for(var x = 0; x < aniArry.length; x++){

              aniResult.push(aniArry[x]);
           }
           callback(aniResult);
       });

    }

 }; 

   module.exports = blah;
```

In the html file

```
var blah = require('./apps2.js');

Blah.ziplist(function(zipResult){

    var select = document.getElementById("zip");  
    for (var i = 0; i < zipResult.length; i++){

        var el = document.createElement('option');
        var opt = zipResult[i];
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
});

Blah.anilist(function(aniResult){

   var select = document.getElementById("ani");  
   for (var i = 0; i < aniResult.length; i++){

       var el = document.createElement('option');
       var opt = aniResult[i];
       el.textContent = opt;
       el.value = opt;
       select.appendChild(el);
   }
});
```